# Table too long for background image at different resolutions

Tags: html, css, html-table, background-image, screen-resolution

ALREADY SOLVED: [Multiple backgrounds on top of each other (Normal, Streched, Normal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663087/multiple-backgrounds-on-top-of-each-other-normal-streched-normal/)

I am currently working on a website for a school project and I'm facing issues with different screen resolutions. My website looks good on my 15.6" laptop at normal resolution, but as soon as I start zooming out, the centered table element gets too long for the background image, since it has a fixed size and cannot strech with the table. My first thought was splitting the background image into 3 parts and streching only the middle one. Does anybody have a more elegant solution and if not, an idea of how to realize this in HTML?

Normal: http://www11.pic-upload.de/26.12.14/opay2lxe63et.png

Zoomed out: http://www11.pic-upload.de/26.12.14/cnrvvumqfcm.png

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<table>
<colgroup>
    <col width="100">
    <col width="300">
    <col width="200">
</colgroup>
<tr>
    <td><b>Episode</b></td>
    <td><b>Title</b></td>
    <td><b>Available Hoster</b></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>01</td>
    <td>Rebirth</td>
    <td>-</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>02</td>
    <td>Confrontation</td>
    <td>-</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>January 28</td>
    <td>-</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>New World</td>
    <td>-</td>
</tr></table></div>
```

CSS:

```
#content{
    width: 1024px;
    height: 950px;
    background: url(img/content_background.png) no-repeat;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#content table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    color: white;
    margin: auto;
}

#content td{
    border: 1px solid white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: you should show what you tried when ask a question.please have a look at these links : 1.http://stackoverflow.com/tour 2.http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I forgot, added them now :)

Comment: so @DavidOnter i see your container is an image of course this will be a problem with the resolution.
the only think u can do is to cut your background-image in to halfs and use a white border. like this http://jsfiddle.net/gfvup12n/1/

Comment: The content would be in the middle one, right? Since it cannot go over different divs...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple backgrounds on top of each other (Normal, Streched, Normal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663087/multiple-backgrounds-on-top-of-each-other-normal-streched-normal)

Answer (score 2):

please use `background-size : 100%;` in your css

Comment: It didn't change anything, probably because the content-div has the exact same size as the background picture. No auto or anything.

Answer (score 0):

dont use only 1 image in background. slice the images as your requirement and use it again. (e.g use top banner image separate and bottom corner icon separate image and border use css border)