# Multiple backgrounds on top of each other (Normal, Stretched, Normal)

Tags: html, css, background-image

Since I [faced an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659851/table-too-long-for-background-image-at-different-resolutions) with the background image beeing too short for the content at different resolutions, I tried to split the background into 3 parts and stretching the middle one automatically to fill the space between the top and bottom image accordingly. Unfortunately I didn't manage to realize this in CSS. How to do this exactly?

content_background_top.png: 1024 x 68px

content_background_middle.png: 1024 x 6px (Stretched)

content_background_bottom.png: 1024 x 71px

Something like this:

```
#content{
    width: 1024px;
    height: 950px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 35px 0 35px 0;
    background: url(img/content_background_top.png), url(img/content_background_middle.png), url(img/content_background_bottom.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1024px 68px, 1024px auto, 1024px 71px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to specify the background-positions and background sizes. Also note that you'll need to list your larger "middle" background last so that it doesn't cover the others.

```css
#content {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 950px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 35px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNQ2g.png?s=128&g=1), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNQ2g.png?s=128&g=1), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNQ2g.png?s=128&g=1);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0% 0%, 0% 100%, 0% 50%;
  background-size: 100px, 100px, cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: I added the code down below, since the mini-Markdown formatting doesn't work :|

Answer (score 0):

```
#content{
    width: 1024px;
    height: 750px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
    background: url(img/content_background_top.png), url(img/content_background_bottom.png), url(img/content_background_middle.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0% 0%, 0% 100%, 0% 50%; /* Order: Top, Bottom, Middle */
    background-size: 1024px 68px, 1024px 71px, 1024px 100%;
}
```